# Chatbase integration dashboard

Tags: api, google-analytics, analytics, chatbot, chatbase

have any way to integrate the dashboard generated in ChatBase with another web page? I would like to present the data generated in another dashboard

dashboard chatbase:

[image: dashboard chatbase example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your question. Chatbase does not currently support report embedding/integration. Our recommended workaround would be to [invite](https://chatbase.com/documentation/collaborators) the external users as viewers to your bot. You can then provide them deeplinks to the Chatbase reports from within their logged in experience on your own site.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate the chatbase with my server in springboot using resttemplate, do you have some quickstart in java or an example to help?

Comment: We do not have a Java specific guide, though any framework should suffice as long as the JSON message body is properly formatted.  Please see our [Quickstart][1] and [Tutorial][2] for specifications on how to format the JSON message body. 

Please feel free to contact chatbase-support@google.com if you have specific questions during the process. 


  [1]: https://chatbase.com/documentation/quickstart
  [2]: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/chatbase/index.html#0